# How to get one div id when it is inside another div

Tags: javascript

I have two rectangles. The bigger one is "house"  and it contains the smaller one "room".
I would like to get alert with div id once I click on any of this rectangles. But when I click on green rectangle I need to get "room" and on red then I need to get "house". Here is the code in the 
https://jsfiddle.net/pr2501/6a4qwdgx/17/
How to make it work?

Html:

```
<div id="house"  onClick="reply_click(this.id)"   style="border: 2px solid red; height:50px;width:50px;padding:15px;">        
        <div id="room"  onClick="reply_click(this.id)"  style="border: 2px solid green; height:25px;width:25px;">           
        </div>
    </div>
```

and JS:

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
  {
      alert(clicked_id);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a single event listener to to `#house`, and get the `id` from the event's target (`e.target`):

```js
document.querySelector('#house')
  .addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
  });
```

```html
<div id="house" style="border: 2px solid red; height:50px;width:50px;padding:15px;">
  <div id="room" style="border: 2px solid green; height:25px;width:25px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use an inline function, set it only on the outer `div`, and pass `event` as param:

```js
function reply_click(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id)
}
```

```html
<div id="house" onClick="reply_click(event)" style="border: 2px solid red; height:50px;width:50px;padding:15px;">
  <div id="room" style="border: 2px solid green; height:25px;width:25px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that I have to clarify that all id are unknown. How to proceed in this case?

Comment: Since you need to add it to containing `div`, the `id` should be known. However, if you don't know the `id`, you can inline it. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The green rectangle is also inside the red rectangle. So when you click inside the inner rectangle the outer rectangle also listens to the event. So, you need to stop the event propagation.

```
  function reply_click(clicked_id)
  {
      alert(clicked_id);
      event.stopPropagation();
  }
```